# Using a toggle switch to act as push button

Tags: computers, button, pulse, toggle-switch

Basically I want to use a toggle switch to turn on my computer. I need some sort of circuit so that the toggle switch will act like a push button. IE, I turn on the toggle switch but it only sends a pulse rather than keep the circuit open.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How long a pulse?   What voltage level?

Comment: What would happen if the toggle switch remained closed and you didn't use a pulse generator circuit?

Comment: Maybe you can get away with a suitable high pass filter and a comparator, depending on the required length of the pulse.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest hardware-wise is:

[image]

Just one small chip with its bypass cap.

The internal pullup on GP0 is enabled, so GP0 will be low when the switch is closed and high when open.  The rest is firmware.  At its simplest, the firmware can just produce a fixed size pulse on GP1 whenever it sees a transition on GP0.  However, unlike dedicated analog solutions, you can apply different policies that might be useful.  For example, when a pulse turns off the system, this could enforce a minimum time to let the system fully shut down before attempting to start it up again.

Comment: Olin,I like your solution but gotta tease you just a little bit.  You broke one of your "soft" schematic rules -- no 4 way junctions.  "Do as I say, not as I do."

Comment: @tcrosley: Yeah, you got me.  Fixed.

Comment: @Olin: do you have any strong reasons of the "soft" rule?Or maybe a post on stack exchange?

Comment: Isn't that because there is no way to tell for sure which wire is effectively connected to the net?

Answer (score 0):

This will work by allowing the 555's trigger input (pin 2) to go high, even if the switch is held closed, in less time than it takes for the 555's output pulse to time out, as long as R3C2 is greater than R2C1.

[image]